# Get a list of requests

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables, I need to get a list of client_id whose last requests (title) have not been processed. We believe that if there was a call after the request was created (created_datetime), then it has been processed.

| tasks |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| client_id | created_datetime | title |

| calls |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| manager_id | client_id | call_datetime |

I think that something needs to be done with time, but I don't understand what.

```
select client_id, max(calls.call_datetime)  - max(tasks.created_datetime) as time
from tasks join calls on tasks.client_id = calls.client_id 
group by client_id, call_datetime
```

Comment: Please read this (and the enclosed links) on why and how to include a Minimal Reproducible Example in your question; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) (Then update your question with representative example data, and the results you want from that example data.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
with maxes as (select client_id, max(calls.call_datetime) latest_call
from calls 
group by client_id)
select tasks.client_id, title 
from tasks 
inner join maxes on maxes.client_id = tasks.client_id
where created_datetime > maxes.latest_call
```

If I understood correctly, this should be it